# using command line to open file

Tags: c++, command-line

I am new to command line, i have a problem. i have searched to solve the problem but none of them work . I want to use command line to open file but i cant open it and i don't know why. I checked if i created my file yet.I did change the working directory, but it still cant  find my file.

My code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void main(int i ,char *a[])
{
    if (i != 1)
    {
        cout << "Wrong!!!";
    }
    fstream fp;
    fp.open(a[1]);
    if (!fp.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Cant open file";
    }

}
```

What did i do wrong??

Comment: What did you do to run above program .?

Comment: Stick with the convention: `argc` and `argv`. You do konw the exe name counts, so that is arg 1. You say anything other than 1 arg is wrong but then open the 2nd arg anyway...

Comment: @radbrawler i use command line to run it 
first i g to disk D:  
then D: cd>New folder\ConsoleAp8\Debug
then ConsoleAp8.exe test1.txt
that's it.

Comment: @John3136 i thought  the exe name count as argv[0] ?, argc just count the statement ,so the file name is first statement ??

Comment: @Van. Right, but an array with 1 member (argc == 1) only has position 1. You say `if (argc != 1) { print wrong }` that implies you expect no args (just the exe name)

Comment: @John3136 ok i understand man. But still cant find my file. DAMN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I changed the program a bit and it worked. Mainly it was argument length

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int i ,char *a[])
{
    if (i != 2)
    {
        cout << "Wrong!!! "<<i;
    }
    fstream fp;
    fp.open(a[1]);
    if (!fp.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Cant open file";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That worked for me.

edit- I ran it on ubuntu. I didn't had windows.